# Aggregating with multiple fields returned in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have a relative simple index with the following fields...

```
"testdata": {
    "properties": {
       "code": {
          "type": "integer"
       },
       "name": {
          "type": "string"
       },
       "year": {
          "type": "integer"
       },
       "value": {
          "type": "integer"
       }
    }
}
```

I can write a query to get the total sum of the values aggregated by the `code` like so:

```
{
  "from":0,
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_code": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "code"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_value": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this returns the following (abridged) results:

```
"aggregations": {
  "by_code": {
     "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 478,
     "sum_other_doc_count": 328116,
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key": 236948,
           "doc_count": 739,
           "total_value": {
              "value": 12537
           }
        },
```

However, this data is being fed to a web front-end, where it is required both the code and the name is displayed. So, the question is, is it possible to amend the query somehow to also return the `name` field, as well as the `code` field, in the results?

So, for example, the results can look a bit like this:

```
"aggregations": {
  "by_code": {
     "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 478,
     "sum_other_doc_count": 328116,
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key": 236948,
           "code": 236948,
           "name": "Test Name",
           "doc_count": 739,
           "total_value": {
              "value": 12537
           }
        },
```

I've read up on sub-aggregations, but in this case there is a one-to-one relationship between `code` and `name` (so, you wouldn't have different names for the same key). Also, in my real case, there are 5 other fields, like `description`, that I would like to return, so I am wondering if there was another way to do it.

In SQL (from which this data originally came from before it was swapped to ElasticSearch) I would write the following query

```
SELECT Code, Name, SUM(Value) AS Total_Value
FROM [TestData] 
GROUP BY Code, Name
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve this using scripting, i.e. instead of specifying a field, you specify a combination of fields:

```
{
  "from":0,
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_code": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "[doc.code.value, doc.name.value].join('-')"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_value": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

note: you need to make sure to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) for this to work